# Get YouTube channel name and link by using Oauth- JS

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, youtube, youtube-api

I was wondering if there was a way to get a user's **Channel name** and the link to the **Channel**, by through the JS `Oauth` from Google.

I don't really understand how that all works.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

No.

All you will get is

```
Array
  (  
    [access_token] => ya29.Glv5AyS0dOSbwvb3beSkQrkNoiBBT******************
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [refresh_token] => 1/wg516U0JybrW0uw*****************
    [token_type] => Bearer
  )
```

However, once you do have an `access_token`, you can make a call like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?access_token=[access_token]&part=snippet&mine=true
```

That should work for you.